# Give a specific user role the ability to edit, delete users other specific role 

Tags: 7, users

I'm working in Drupal 7.

I want to give to a specific user role named "test role" the ability to edit, and delete users whose role is *students*.
Users with that role should not modify the admin account, and any other account with other roles.

Comment: May I suggest some grammatical improvements should be made? The currently posted answer looks good, but could be incorrect due to what I perceive as a possibly ambiguous question.

Comment: @Letharion Which part is not clear, to you?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a combination of the following:

http://drupal.org/project/role_delegation - Adds a permission to assign roles per role
http://drupal.org/project/administerusersbyrole - Allows controlling, based on roles, which users can admin which other users.

Comment: I need a module like http://drupal.org/project/administerusersbyrole for the Drupal 7.  I'll update the post with the version I'm working now.  Thanks for the options.